# Unable to install or run the application....in Desktop Application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I had developed a Desktop Application in .Net. I had published and deployed it in my Client's System. But while my client running that setup, an error message is displayed :

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnastics.STrace Version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first

What should I do for this ?

Comment: You need to include this file as a prerequisite in your setup program

Comment: sorry, i cant able to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this dll is not present in Global Assembly Cache.

you can add an `assembly` to `GAC` by following command:

```
GACUTIL –i <Path to Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll>
```

Comment: i had run this GACUTIL –i <Path to Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll> 
in cmd prompt....."The syntax of the command is incorrct" is coming

Comment: Run it in the visual studio command promt or run it in the framework directory actually containing the Gacutil.exe

Comment: He is asking to solve this issue from development server side.

Answer (score 2):

Open project Properties form Solution explorer in visual studio

> Properties->Publish -> Application Files

In Applications Files window check Show all files at the right bottom. change publish Status of **"Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll"**  **"Prerequisite(Auto)"** to Include click ok and publish Application.

Comment: The op is asking about Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnastics.STrace not Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll. I have this same issue and tried setting the publish status to "Prerequisite (Auto)" and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

to find if STrace.dll file is present on your client computer, you can search it with this command line:
    dir Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll /s

if the file is found, use the previous anwser command line to add the dll to the global asembly cache

If not, you have to add this file as prerequisit in your deployment project 
if you have a setup project (lik installshield / MS setup project / Clickonce project, the prerequisit can be added on your setup project properties.

when you add a prerequisit, you should be able to choose if the prerequisit has to be packaged with your application or downloaded from the publisher site.

Comment: how do you deploy your app on the client computer?

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was I had to do what @ShahidRaees did except include all of the assemblies.  I selected all of them except for the file ending in .pdb.

Selecting all of them should automatically update the GAC when you install the program, but I'm not 100% sure.